# Lifetime issues of QString

Tags: c++, qt, lifetime

I have a class like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public:
        QString data;
        SomeClass(const QString &);
};
```

and in the .cpp file:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(const QString &_data) {
    data = _data;
}
```

then I use it like this:

```
SomeClass c("foobar");
```

This will call QString("foobar") and will pass it to the constructor of the SomeClass. But this QString is an automatic object so its lifetime will be gone after the constructor. On the other hand `data` won't be copied(as far as I understand Qt docs) unless modified. Is it possible to have lifetime issues with this code or am I wrong? How to design it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All is OK. When you destroy your temporary QString data is modified, so copy would be performed. Data modification means that it will be modified at any side, in string that references data or in string that contains data.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is ok. The sequence of events is:

1. a temporary QString (let us call it xx) is created when you pass the const char* "foobar" to the constructor
2. data is assigned that string, i.e. both data and xx reference the string body which now has a ref count of 2
3. xx goes out of scope, the ref count of the string body goes to 1 and data still references this body.